# Flash Animation to android animation

Tags: java, android, flash, android-animation

I have wonderful flash animation with sound which I developed, I would like to implement the same to my Android app. Is this possible? It is a 6 seconds splash screen for flash

If so how? Can some one guide me to get this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library, what you need:  https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/master/vitamio-sample